# Visual Studio project organization and references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, organization

I have a solution in VS 2010.

We have project A, B, and C in this solution.

Project A includes Project B as a reference. When I include Project A as a reference in project C, C doesn't understand anything from project B unless I also make a reference to it. To me it seems that since Project A includes Project B and Project C includes A that C should understand what B is. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a setting I should set when making the reference of Project B into A?

I want to keep Project B separated because it could be used by many projects as a base for the class setup, so just making that code part of A is not possible.

Comment: Just reference both A and B from C if you need B directly from C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project C must be using type members defined in Project B, so it needs a reference to Project B.  To avoid this, you would need to completely *encapsulate* the Project B features you want inside the functionality of Project A.

As a simplified example, lets suppose:

1. Project A is `DogWalker`, a project for managing a dog walking business
2. Project B is `RouteCalculator`, a project for finding the most effective routes between different places
3. Project C is `MyDogWeb`, an ASP.NET web project for dog walkers

You have a page in `MyDogWeb` that calculates and displays the fastest route to pick up all the dogs you need to walk.  It does that using `DogWalker` and `DogWalker` internally uses `RouteCalculator`.  When you want to display a route, there might be two options:

1. `DogWalker.Routes.GetPickupRoute As RouteCalculator.RouteTable`
2. `DogWalker.Routes.MapPickupRoute(writer As HtmlTextWriter)`

If you use the first option, `MyDogWeb` will **require** a reference to `RouteCalculator` becuase it is interacting with the `RouteCalculator.RouteTable` class directly.  If you use the second option, `MyDogWeb` **will not** require a reference to `RouteCalculator` beacuse it never interacts with the `RouteCalculator` classes.

Comment: ok I guess what you are saying makes sense that both projects use references from the base level included. It would just seems that since DogWalker already includes the dll for RouteCalculator that any project that references DogWalker would be able to use RouteCalculator.  cont...

Comment: In my example I am creating a base project for data layer that automatically adds CRUD operations for EF5. any data layer created would implemented this base dal to quickly give us crud operations on any db. but then any project that includes a main data layer project also has to include the base repository project. I guess its because of how I have the constructors working referencing an interface from the base dal project so you can resuse the context. I will continue to think on this and see if there is a better structure that I should be using in my situation. Thanks

Comment: @kharr1027 `DogWalker` does not *include* `RouteCalculator`, it references it and uses components from it.  They remain 100% separate DLL's.  (If you look at the compiler output for `DogWalker`, you'll see it includes `RouteCalculator.dll`).

Answer (score 0):

I think John is right, if you're directly using things in B from C, you need to reference B explicitly, and is reasonable that you should. If instead you're only indirectly using things in B by using things in A that internally use things in B, you shouldn't need the additional reference. An exception is user control projects, where I have seen designer/compiler issues if all references aren't made even if only indirectly used.

Using a project as a base in multiple other projects is a good idea and may want to be either added to several solution files simultaneously or more robustly, built and deployed as a compiled library to reference against. This way you can use versioning to keep changes in your library trackable and easier to manage changes to in its dependents.